# android progressBar problem

Tags: android

i have a button that on click is loading rss feed.i want to load a progress bar until my list opens.i have created a progressbar,it works,but as i press the return button to return to the main menu the progress bar appears again and it doesnt stop(and not even let me see my menu).this is my code

```
ProgressBar myProgressBar;
  int myProgress = 0;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
  super.onCreate(icicle);
  setContentView(R.layout.main1);

  Button nea = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nea);
   nea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick (View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.bar);

     myProgressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.bar);

           new Thread(myThread).start();

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), nea.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);


   }  

  });

}
```

and then,out of the onCreate

```
  private Runnable myThread = new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     while (myProgress<100){
      try{
       myHandle.sendMessage(myHandle.obtainMessage());
       Thread.sleep(1000);
      }
      catch(Throwable t){
      }
     }
    }

    Handler myHandle = new Handler(){

     public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      myProgress++;
      myProgressBar.setProgress(myProgress);
     }
    };
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity isn't getting recreated when you return from the startActivityForResult Activity you started, so you contentView is stuck as R.layout.bar .

Try overriding the onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) method and 
calling  setContentView(R.layout.main1); inside of it to reset your view. You may need to add the listener to the button again.